# Use jQuery to update CSS transform values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

I'm just wondering if its possible to updated CSS `transform` values using jQuery on a click event?

If not has anybody recommendations on how I could replicate the below?

I'm trying the following but get nothing from it...

```
$('.reset').on('click',function(){
    $('.zoomer-holder').css(
        'transform','translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px) scale(0.2525, 0.2525)'
    );
});
```

Comment: What type of element is the one that has the `zoomer-holder` class?

Comment: Without knowing your code, you might want to use addClass/removeClass/toggleClass instead, to seperate your concerns

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. Try this:

```
$('.reset').on('click',function(){
    $('.zoomer-holder').css(
        'transform','translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px) scale(0.2525, 0.2525)'
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out with all the vendor prefixes.
Probably '-webkit-transform', '-moz-transform', etc. all at once.

```
$('.zoomer-holder')
    .css('-webkit-transform','translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px) scale(0.2525, 0.2525)')
    .css('-moz-transform','translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px) scale(0.2525, 0.2525)')
    .css('transform','translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px) scale(0.2525, 0.2525)');
```

Comment: What web browser are you trying that in, by the way?

Comment: I'm trying in Chrome and Firefox @myTerminal, the above doen't work neither I'm afraid!

Comment: Does it not apply the value or does it not reflect on the page?

Comment: It has no effect at all @myTerminal

Comment: It seems to be working fine at my browser. Could you double-check the class name `.zoomer-holder`? :) And also check if the event handler works at the first place, does it get inside the function?